# Any way to autofill links in Googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Googlesheet with 2 tabs containing 148 rows of member information.  I have created a link in Cell P3 in Tab A which when clicked takes me to the relevant cell in Tab B.  My query is ....is there any way of copying/auto filling this link formula in Cell P3 for all 148 rows rather than having to manually create the link for all 148 members?  Copy/Paste or auto filling doesn't seem to work for links.
Thanks!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [HYPERLINK()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313) to insert links:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXX/edit#gid=xxxxxx&range="&address(row($A1),1,4),"CellLink")
```

**What you need to do?**

1. Replace the sheet URL until gid=xxxxxx
2. Replace the row and column index in [ADDRESS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308) based on your preference.

**What it does?**

- It creates a hyperlink that will link to a specific cell by appending `&range=<A1 notation>` to the sheet's url
- [ADDRESS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308) will return an `A1 notation` based on the row and column index that you provide. In this example, I want to increment the row index. I used [ROW()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316) and reference to `A1` so that the row index returned will be 1.

**If you drag-down the formula, it should look like this:**

```
= HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXX/edit#gid=xxxxxx&range="&address(row($A1),1,4),"CellLink")

= HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXX/edit#gid=xxxxxx&range="&address(row($A2),1,4),"CellLink")

== HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXX/edit#gid=xxxxxx&range="&address(row($A3),1,4),"CellLink")

so on..
```

**Output:**

[image]